# How to integrate Play Framework Application Scala with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scala, playframework

I want to know that how can I integrate my Application.scala with my angularjs(app.js) using Play framework. I'm doing some exercise with: https://github.com/NeelSachdeva/fileUpload .   If I run my application(It consists of angularjs and above fileUpload task), it is executing only my Application.scala controller(means my file Upload task only) but not exusting my app.js file(which is having some tabs-angular code). Otherwise is there any chance to execute the above functionality in my app.js tabs(in my html files) I hope I'm missing some integration part for both(Application.scala and it's scala.htmls and app.js) in some where ? Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: I don't know how to do this but you could try one of many activator templates that show how it's done eg. this one: https://github.com/typesafehub/angular-seed-play#master

Comment: Keep in mind that angular-seed-play haven't been updated since a while.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, I've tried my application like above, but I'm getting error like: Unresolved dependency: com.typesage.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.0 not found . I'm using Play (2.2.3).

Answer (score 0):

[Play Yeoman](https://github.com/tuplejump/play-yeoman) is an excellent SBT plugin which brings the streamlined frontend development workflow and optimized build system of yeoman to Play. With this it's very easy to integrate Angular into a Play app.

Please have a look at the [Play Silhouette Angular Seed](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed) template as an example implementation.

Comment: Hi akkie, Thanks for your reply, I will check it once.